# Creating a list of existing dictionaries in python

Tags: python

I need to get a list of some dictionaries that I defined before.The dictionaries look like these:
`dic1={"D":1.4,"SD":1.4} dic2={"D":1.2,"SD":1.2,"L":1.6,"LR":1.6,"LR0.5":1.6,"LP":1.6,"LRF":0.5} dic3={"D":1.2,"SD":1.2,"L":1,"LR":1,"LR0.5":1,"LP":1,"LRF":1.6}`
And I expect a list like this:

```
list=[{"D":1.4,"SD":1.4},{"D":1.2,"SD":1.2,"L":1.6,"LR":1.6,"LR0.5":1.6,"LP":1.6,"LRF":0.5},                                                                               {"D":1.2,"SD":1.2,"L":1,"LR":1,"LR0.5":1,"LP":1,"LRF":1.6}]
```

How can I create it using a loop in python?

Comment: Do you mean simply `[dic1,dic2,dic3]`?

Comment: Yes. I need a list of these dictionaries.but there are a lot of dictionaries so i don't wanna do it without a loop.

Comment: If there are so many, then instead of creating them as `dic1`, `dic2`, etc. just keep appending them to a list as you create them: `lis.append({"D":1.4,"SD":1.4})`. Or use the method in the answer below which includes _all_ dictionaries in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list(filter(lambda a: type(a) == dict, locals().values()))
```

Will return all local variables with `dict` type as a list

Comment: Thank you, but there is a null dict using this. some thing like that:
[{}, {'DEAD': 1.4, 'SD': 1.4}, {'DEAD': 1.2, 'SD': 1.2, 'LIVE': 1.6, 'LR': 1.6, 'LR0.5': 1.6, 'LP': 1.6, 'LRF': 0.5}]

Comment: @FZL just remove it from the list then...

Comment: @FZL then you want something like: `dict(filter(lambda i: type(i[1]) == dict and not i[0].startswith('__'), locals().items())).values()`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include **all** the dictionaries, do something like this:

```
lyst = []

# Define dic1
dic1 = {}
lyst += [dic1]

# Code

dic2 = {}
lyst += [dic2]

# etc...
```

Append the dictionaries to the list as you create them.

Of course, if you want to include all the dictionaries in the script, use @Daniil Ryzhkov's answer.